# How did the anthropologist in The Relic get to the museum?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-relic

I rewatched The Relic (1997) last night and there's one thing I don't understand.

At the beginning the anthropologist John Whitney is seen asking the ship's captain to unload some boxes. Presumably he does not want the boxes with the leaves to reach the museum having (somehow) figured out what they do.

When the ship reaches the USA everyone on the ship is dead and he is not there, but the boxes are sent anyway to the museum I guess?

In any case my actual question is: how did he manage to get from the ship to the museum? Also how did the boxes arrive if they were not in the ship?

Comment: I'm not sure I remember correctly, but wasn't the anthropologist actually the monster, transformed by the leaves or whatever? Presumably he was in one of the boxes that got kind of auto-delivered from the ship to the museum?

Comment: Yes he was, but the crates where empty except for the leaves and the statue thingy. They mention this several times